How to Add PDF Attachments to Emails in Magento 2.4.6?
I am trying to implement email attachments in Magento 2.4.6. Despite extensive research, most of the solutions I've come across seem outdated or incompatible with the latest version of Magento.
If anyone has a working example, detailed steps, or guidance on how to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate your support. Additionally, if you know of any reliable resources related to this topic, please feel free to share them.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Why magento is not doing this in core I don't know...but here is the way
Create your own custom addAttachment method
    /**
     * @param $content
     * @param $fileName
     * @param $fileType
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addAttachment($content, $fileName, $fileType)
    {
        $attachmentPart = $this->partFactory->create();
        $attachmentPart->setContent($content)
            ->setType($fileType)
            ->setFileName($fileName)
            ->setDisposition(Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT)
            ->setEncoding(Mime::ENCODING_BASE64);
        $this->attachments[] = $attachmentPart;

        return $this;
    }

You can do that by extending core magento transport builder
    <preference for="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" type="Vendor\Module\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" />
Then all you have to do is call your method where you need it; as per example
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier($templateId)
                ->setTemplateOptions($templateOptions)
                ->setTemplateVars(
                    [
                        'data' => new DataObject($post)
                    ]
                )
                ->setFromByScope(
                    array(
                        'name' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('lastname'),
                        'email' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('email')
                    )
                )
                ->addTo($setFromByScope['email'], $setFromByScope['name'])
                ->addAttachment(file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']), $file['name'], $file['type'])
                ->getTransport();

